# Dominion: ghost plus pixie

Tags: dominion, dominion-nocturne

Ghost card says to play an action twice. The pixie is an action that allows you to trash it when you play it. What happens if I ghost a pixie? If I trash pixie the first time, do I still play it the second time?

Comment: Welcome. I haven't played Dominion - is this description of the sequence adequate for a casual player to understand the context of your question? Also, please put your question in the title for so that searches work properly.

Comment: [Related but different.](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1996/dominion-what-happens-when-i-play-throne-room-on-a-feast-since-feast-gets-trash?rq=1). In the linked question, the result is different because Feast gaining a card is not dependent upon it being trashed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The golden rule in Dominion is *follow the card instructions as much as possible*. You can play Pixie a second time, even if it has been moved, e.g., moved to the trash. However, you may not be able to execute some conditional effects, e.g., trash the card. So here is how a Throne Room/Pixie or Ghost/Pixie plays:

1. Play Throne Room; choose an action card.
2. Play Pixie once.

   - +1 Card, +1 Action
   - Discard top boon (*Boon1*).
   - Trash Pixie; receive *Boon1* twice.
3. Play Pixie a second time. *Note that Pixie is now in the trash.*

   - +1 Card, +1 Action
   - Discard top boon (*Boon2*)
   - Pixie cannot be trashed, so you cannot receive *Boon2*, neither once nor twice.

Same goes with Ghost and any similar card (e.g., *King's Court* from Dominion: Prosperity, *Royal Carriage* from Dominion: Adventures, etc). No matter now many times you play Pixie, you can only trash the card once. But you always get the +1 Card +1 Action.