# Dominion Nocturne Necromancer and Pixie rules

Tags: dominion, dominion-nocturne

I think I know the answer to the problem but I have some doubts and I need confirmation or an explanation to which I can point when this happens again.

I have the following scenario in Dominion Nocturne.

The following to 2 cards are in the game:

- [Pixie](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Pixie)

  - +1 Card / +1 Action / Discard the top Boon. You may trash this to receive that Boon twice.
  - [image: pixie]
- [Necromancer](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Necromancer)

  - Play a face up, non-Duration Action card from the trash, leaving it there and turning it face down for the turn.
  - [image: necromancer]

in a previous turn, one of the players played and trashed Pixie. So now there is a pixie in the trash.

In my turn, I play Necromancer which allows me to play a card from the trash. I choose to play "Pixie".
Now the question. Can I trash the trashed pixie to receive the next boon twice? or I just get the "1 card 1 action" and I discard the top boon?

Based on what [Adama](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/10362/adama) wrote as [an answer on a different question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/43325/23084) ....

> The golden rule in Dominion is follow the card instructions as much as possible. [...] However, you may not be able to execute some conditional effects, e.g., trash the card

I conclude that I cannot trash an already trashed card, but there is a chance I got this wrong. So...which is it? can I or I cannot trash a trashed card?

Comment: I might post an answer later, but Dominion Strategy Wiki addresses this exact combo [here](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Necromancer). Since Pixie checks that it was trashed, it wasn’t so you wont get the boon.

Comment: I read that sentence but I did not make much sense. The wording on it is not the "happiest" specially for a non native English speaker (or at least for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Stop-Moving_rule#Official_Rules:

> - If a card isn't where the effect would expect it to be, or has moved away from there and then back, it can't move the card.
>
>   - Played cards expect to be in play; they can't move themselves if they aren't.

Because the Pixie is not in play, it cannot trash itself (and you cannot get the Boon).

Answer (score 1):

The definition of trashing is to put a card into the Trash pile. Necromancer states: leaving it there. That means, you can't trash the card since it is never yours/ in your hand.

Comment: this is what I suspected.

Comment: Being "in your hand" is irrelevant: if the Pixie is played by [March](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/March), it can be trashed.

Comment: That is why I wrote yours. March is using the discard pile and not the trash pile

Comment: Honestly wish you could trash the Necromancer to do the effect